# How does readLine iterate in Java?

Tags: java

How does readLine iterate for the code below? I mean, there's no index that is being incremented like iterating through an array so how does it go from one line to another line? Thanks!

```
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader (file)); 
while (true) {
    String s = br.readLine(); 
    if (s == null) 
        break; 
    ... 
}
```

code below works the same and same question as above.

```
String s;
while ( (s = br.readLine()) != null) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BufferedReader` reads the file as a stream of sequential characters. Therefore, there is no need to expose the pointer of the current location. On the other hand, a `RandomAccessFile` reads the file non-sequentially thus the method exposing the current location of the file i.e. `getFilePointer()` is available and can be used for knowing the current file location.

So if your application requires the knowledge of current file pointer location then you may use `RandomAccessFile`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

There's an internal pointer within the BufferedReader that advances with each call of `read(...)` or `readLine()`.